# Proving a symmetric group is a subgroup

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Warning: This is a homework question. I only need help on understanding the set.

Question: Suppose $n>2$ Is $H$ a subgroup of $S_n$

$H=\{f \in S_n : f \bullet 1=1  $ and $f \bullet 2=2\} $

My problem for being unable to answer the question is that I am struggling to understand how the word "and" affects the question. In terms of proving/disproving it I would proceed with the sub-group test.

Comment: What do you denote $f\bullet 1,2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is asking, "If you look at all permutations of $n$ items (i.e., $S_n$), there are some that leave the items 1 and 2 fixed. Call the set of those $H$. Is it a subgroup of $S_n$ or not?"

For $S_4$, the set $H$ consists of

1. The identity permutation, and
2. The permutation that swaps items 3 and 4.

Comment: I understand that set H fixes 1 and 2, but why are 3 and 4 in the set H in your example?

Comment: $3$ and $4$ are not in $H$ - those aren't permutations. But in case $n=4$, the permutation $(34)$ *is* in $H$ - and it's the only non-trivial permutation in H.

Comment: The numbers 3 and 4 are **not** in my set; they're the names of two of the four items being permuted. Why four? Because we're working in $S_4$. My set contains exactly two elements, each of which is a *permutation*.

Comment: So in the Set H, if the "and" was swapped with "or" how would that change the set exactly?

Comment: Suppose $f$ and $g$ fix both $1$ and $2$, so they belong to $H$. What are you left to prove, then, to conclude whether $H$ is or isn't a subgroup?

Comment: If a permutation fixes BOTH $1$ and $2$, then it fixes also EITHER $1$ OR $2$, but not vice versa. So, say, $H_{and} \subseteq H_{or}$